# Enum таблица в rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Есть такая таблица

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

можно ли обращаться к строкам по какому то уникальному имени? Что то вроде

```
User.where(role: :admin)
```

Comment: Можно, но эти имена должны где-то храниться. В вашем примере я не вижу, где лежит `admin`.

Comment: Вопрос в том и заключается, где хранить эти имена?

Comment: Да хоть в БД отдельной колонкой, это первое что приходит в голову.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понимаю, то вы хотите сделать распределение пользователей по ролям. Для этого у вас есть несколько вариантов:

1. Писать роли в отдельной колонке этой же таблицы (добавьте колонку role в таблицу)
2. Сделать отдельную таблицу roles, и добавить внешний ключ в таблицу users. То есть в таблице users появится колонка role_id. Это позволит вам динамически добавлять/удалять роли, не трогая код.
3. Сделать отдельную таблицу roles и связующую таблицу, например users_roles и юзать связи с [through](http://rusrails.ru/active-record-associations#the-has-many-through-association)